# scrambled data when printing in google chrome and safari through javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, printing, safari

I have a JS function which prints the contents of a particular div called **divDisplay** of my html page ( the half bottom part of the page ), when someone clicks a button. The contents of this div are received dynamically ( ajax ) when the user interacts with the page. Printing works perfectly in FF,OPERA,IE but the data is scrambled, without color and out of the correct position ( as if there is no css formatting ) in chrome and safari in the pop up window to be printed.

```
function jsPrintDiv(m) {

    glblPopupWindow = window.open("", "PrintWindow", "width=1024,height=768,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes");
    glblPopupWindow.document.write('<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"></head><body><div name="divDisplay" id="divDisplay">' + document.getElementById(m).innerHTML + '</div></body></html>');
    glblPopupWindow.document.close();
    glblPopupWindow.document.getElementById("divDisplay").style.top = "0px";

    glblPopupWindow.focus();
    glblPopupWindow.print();
    glblPopupWindow.close();

}
```

**styles.css** is the same css file that the original html page where the printing is taking place has. the same goes for the **doctype**.

the css of **divDisplay**:

```
#divDisplay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0.2%;
    top: 305px;
    width: 99.6%;
    bottom: 0.5%;
    /* height: expression(document.body.offsetHeight - 314 + "px"); */
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #AACCFF;
    font-family: palatino linotype;
    font: palatino linotype;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Any ideas what i may be doing wrong? thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

correct data in pop window to be printed ( firefox ):
http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/8195/ffprint.jpg

scrambled data in pop window to be printed ( chrome ):
http://img152.imageshack.us/img152/6108/chprint.jpg

**EDIT2:**
if i comment out the

```
glblPopupWindow.print();
```

line, chrome displays it correctly. dunno if that helps.

Comment: The html has absolute or relative positioning???

Comment: @Varun yes divDisplay has absolute positioning. i updated the initial post. However the trouble appears in the internal data of divdisplay, they look scrambled, colorless out of position etc. etc

Comment: There are a lot of issues of position absolute and relative in multiple browsers, would be really great if you can work out and create fluid layouts

Comment: this may be css issue  try to code some webkit css hacks for reference please see the link and you can have many links to make it better desing http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

Comment: Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The firefox window that you show, isn't the print preview from firefox.  The screen shot is the actual pop-up window, that's why it looks correct.  If you were to open the page in firefox, and go to 'file'-> 'print preview' I bet it would look very similar to what you are seeing in Chrome.

When you print a web page it won't always look the same as it does when you view it.  You can add a print style sheet for the page that should be printed, or you can add the print styling to an existing sheet.  In your CSS specify styles for printing:

```
@media print {
    /* Your Styles Here */
}
```

Also, browsers can interpret printing web pages differently. Defining good css for printing a site is a real pain.  Good luck.

Comment: yes it wasn't the print preview window, just the pop-up window, and yes the print preview in firefox is scrambled too but it gets printed correctly as seen in the pop up. I will check and see what I can do with @media print. thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  Like I said, trying to make printing styling is a real pain.